# Swift Array extension with optionals

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type, swift-extensions

I've created simple extension for Array which will append only unique elements. It works fine until I want to work with an array of optionals. Since that I'm keep getting error 
`Type 'Event?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'`

**Event class**

```
import RealmSwift
class Event: Object,Equatable {
    dynamic var id = ""
}

func ==(lhs: Event, rhs: Event) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

**Extension**

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    mutating func appendUniqueContentOf(elements:[Element]){
        for ele in elements {
            if (!contains(ele)){
                append(ele)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var newEvents:[Event] = someEvents()
var events = [Event?]()
events.appendUniqueContentOf(newEvents)
```

**Question**
I don't understand this situation. `Event` class conform that protocol. I've also tried adding other combination of `==` function, but without success.

I don't know how to approah this issue. Is it matter of my extension? How I should properly approach it? Could you show me right track?

Comment: `Event` conforms to `Equatable`, but `Event?` does not. Also `events` and `newEvents` have a different type.

Comment: implementing Equatable for Optionals should not be needed : [link](http://natashatherobot.com/swift-equatable-with-optionals/), but even if you do it does not work.

Comment: Making this work for optionals would also be pretty useless. There will only ever be one optional that is nil inside the appended array, since nil is a value.

Comment: @RMenke I have this situation when actions of one viewController affect on secon viewController data. But I guess I have to use delegates for that.

Comment: @Dudi if it is between VCa and VCb, always just use delegation. It is simple and well documented. If it is between VCA and VCz and there is no linear path between them, I would use a Singleton.

Comment: @RMenke yes there is no linear path and I thought about singleton but that path looks ugly for me. I thought using optionals would be much universal and will be sign of good practice. But what can you do :).

Comment: @Dudi Optionals are not a design pattern where a Singleton is. So you can't really say that optionals are good or bad practice, it's all about how they are used. I still don't know what you are exactly trying to achieve, but a Singleton that works like a central delegate for all VC's and dispatches the data might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

`Event?` is syntactic sugar for `Optional<Event>`. Since `Optional` does not conform to `Equatable`, neither will `Optional<Event>`.

Though possible, I highly discourage implementing `Equatable` for `Optional`. This being said, you should probably rethink and try using just `Array<Event>`.